# deploying flex application on web server issue

Tags: php, apache-flex, deployment, flex4

I have a simple flex application that can upload local files. It is a simple button, and on click event a file dialog appear.

The selected files are then processed by a PHP script and works great on my local machine. When i try to move my flex-debug, or flex-release project to a remote server the upload functionality doesn't work any more.

If a inspect the network the POST is executed but for some reasons it has status of pending for 1 minute, but after success is doesn't run well, as expected, the files are not uploaded.

```
// file is a file:FileReference object
var uploadURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var params:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadComplete);
params.maxSize = maxSize;
uploadURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
uploadURL.data = params;
uploadURL.url = uploadScript;
file.upload(uploadURL, IMAGE_FIELD);
file.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, uploadDataComplete);
file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadComplete);
```

Edit: When i try to move my debug folder generated from Flash Builder 4.5 from C:\www to my second local host on D:\www the upload script doesn't work anymore. Maybe i miss some deployment options and only sees it on C:\www where my .mxml reside.

Edit2: There was a problem on remote server i.e. move upload file function was not working properly. The problem was from upload.php script and not from Flex after all, thanks for help and sorry for disturbance.

Comment: Are you uploading to a different domain than the one the swf is hosted on? That said, I think using a Flex application (and having the user download 300+Kb) is overkill for a simple upload button.

Comment: To upload a file you should use the FileReference.upload() http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#upload%28%29 .  It is not clear to me, from the code you provided, what you're using.

Comment: have you checked the folder security/permissions? Upload failure mostly occurs as per write issue. Besides filesize is also a hurdle but I guess u have already checked that as somebody already pointed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://{you_site_domain}/upload.php");
```

and check

```
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
```

Comment: Flash should work fine with relative URLs; there should be no need to specify the full domain name.

Comment: @Flextras: yes, but as he specifies inside his update, he is using paths to "c:" frive... which is not relative any more.

Answer (score 1):

There are few points i guess you should check-

1) The service path you are using, recheck it again with running in browser addressbar.
2) Check the upload path folder permission.

Comment: Can you provide your service path?

Comment: Flex can communicates with PHP with 3 ways only -

1) HTTPService
2) WebService
3) Remoting (AMFPHP or any other)

So which one you are using and how you are using?

Answer (score 1):

1) provide service path or similar example.

2) How big is the uploaded file, have you tested with under 2Mb (default php.ini allows just 
small file size)

3) What is the exact error message that you get ?

4) can you listen for ProgressEvent, maybe your upload is just slow... and you use a big file.

5) listen for IOErrorEven.IO_ERROR and SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR

Comment: What I wanted to ask on 1) was and uploadURL.url = uploadScript; example. Also can you check your php logs on the server ?